# stackable.js the table background color not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a table, I want to use stackable.js (http://johnpolacek.github.io/stacktable.js/) for making responsive for mobile , my table have specific background color in base of type of data , so in desktop my table works fine, but when reduce size , the background color of table disappear:

in this example the red background of some line when reduce disappear , how make this function also in mobile.

```
<table id="gestione_aree" class="tabella_prezzi">
                  <tr class="etichette bitsmall">
              <th width="50%">
                  <a href="/amministra/gestione_aree/index.php?ord=denominazione&desc=0#inizio_tabella" title="Ordina per NOME">nome</a>
              </th>............... continue on codepen
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwvJxa

Answer (score 0):

So the class is copied from your original table and added to what stackable creates. You must apply the `background-color` to your table's class in your CSS file:

```
.tabella_prezzi { background-color: #ff0000; }
```

Updated your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJMWpY

Comment: @themich Since your color is dynamic from server-side, simply add a class specific for what color you need instead of inline style.

Comment: @themich And the reason desktop works and mobile doesn't is because mobile is a recreated element, not the same one you created. It takes the classes from your table and applies them to the mobile elements.

Comment: yes i have already implemented on php file, but if use stackable.js, change a class of line so not reproduce the color background of specific line, so this problem depend by stackable,js with a customization, for not replace the style of desktop version, this my question

Comment: create multiple classes. one for each color you need.

Comment: have a solution for applied without recreate a class  in table ??

Comment: Unfortunately, that's how stackable.js works. If you want styling to persist between screen sizes then you must set them in classes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying a background colour to the `tr`, add a class to the `tr`.

This class will get added to both the tables `small-only` and `large-only`.

Then add the background colour in css.

check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/s9tsL5yt/

Added this sample css

```
.bgcolor{
    background: red !important;
}
```

Comment: i think you don't unterstand my question, the background color of line depends by php function , and it's have more color depend by function result,  you simple css is a static css, the problem is , why in desktop it's show the background color whereas with stackable.js in mobile versione not show, the html table i have show in codepen is a result of a php page result.

Comment: the inline style is not applied to the other table generated for mobile

Comment: have a solution for applied without recreate a class  in table ??

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the javascript to add the styles also to the `tr` in mobile table. Right now it only adds the class.

Please check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/s9tsL5yt/1/

Added an additional class `tr_style` in js to get the styles also.

Comment: good, now work with this table, but have other table and not work , view please http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJMXeJ

Comment: here background colour is applied to `td`. is it possible to add style to the `tr` instead?

Comment: i have more table , for me is more simple if work only with javascript, so it's possible also for TD copy the style in mobile ?